# Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I was using ember-data previously within the project, but then I switched to ember-model. I deleted any files accessing the DS class.

However, when I build and compile the project, the application still makes calls to the old files that contained reference to DS.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're still using DS in your project.

From the browser it will tell you which file, and what line in the console.  You should be able to track down orphaned DS references.